# How to join two mysql tables in my Django application

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have two tables in my MySQL database:

First Table: For Subscribers (id, name, area, subscriberNumber, phoneNumber)

Second Table: For Monthly Payment (id, subscriberNumber, month, year, amount, discount, fine, billNumber)

I have a HTML page where the list of the Subscriber. Whenever the admin clicks on one of the subscriber the detail of the user is shown.But currently I can only show the user detail(from the first table). I want the page to show the list of payments he/she has done throughout the year(from the second table). I want to join the tables and show the details of both the table in one HTML page.

This is the code to display the data of the first table in views.py

```
@login_required
def userDetail(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Subscribers.objects.using('db2'), id=id)
    context = {
        "Name": instance.name,
        "instance": instance,
    }
    return render(request, 'userDetail.html', context)
```

How do I show the payments done by the user on the same page as their details are in?

Models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Subscribers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    installationCost = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    subsNumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("userDetail", kwargs={"id": self.id})


class Payments(models.Model):
    month = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    discount = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    fine = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    billNumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subsNumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("userDetail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

Comment: Can you post `models.py`?

Comment: I am edited the question with models.py @Arun

Comment: Add a `ForeignKey` to link them both.

Comment: How can I use `ForeignKey` @The_Cthulhu_Kid can you please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why to use to much of confusion??

do this instead

```
instance = Subscribers.objects.using('db2').get(id=id)
payment_info = Payments.objects.using('db2').get(subsNumber=instance.subsNumber)
context = {
    "Name": instance.name,
    "instance": instance,
    "payment": payment_info
}
```

Comment: I did that a while ago @Exprator but the same error comes up `Payments matching query does not exist.`

Comment: tell me a thing is subsnumber same for both the models ?? if they are not same you will get that error, try to change the number to a number that subscribers has for a user and then try it for that subscriber

Comment: see either you got to keep same subsNumber in both the tables or you have to use ForeignKey mapping to help this matter

Comment: I am closing the whole project. Please wait for a minute. Mysql is not working. Sorry

Comment: Yeah it worked. I had the subsNumber in both the table. I dont know what the problem was, but it worked. Thanks bro

Answer (score 2):

To show the payment of a user you can use:

```
instance = get_object_or_404(Subscribers.objects.using('db2'), id=id)
try:    
    payment_info = Payments.objects.using('db2').get(subsNumber=instance.subsNumber)
except Payments.DoesNotExist:
    payment_info = None
context = {
    "Name": instance.name,
    "instance": instance,
    "payment": payment_info
}
```

Comment: `Payments matching query does not exist.` error is shown when I use the above code

Comment: I am closing the whole project. Please wait for a minute. Mysql is not working. Sorry

Comment: hey your previous ans worked just fine. Dont know what the problem was. I restarted the whole app and it worked. thanks